# Increase spacing between plotlines on x axis in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm getting time series data from the server including data for events which need to be marked as plotlines on the chart. Now if the event data contains points as close as 5 seconds apart, the plotlines almost overlap. I will never get event data closer than 5 seconds. What I want is to have some padding between plotlines for a reasonable amount of time series data, say till about 1 hour.

I've tried increasing pointWidth and pointPadding as shown in the code snippet below but that didn't work. I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/illusionist/43hewecb/1/) for reference which depicts the issue for 20 mins worth of data. I'm using highcharts v4.9.x.

`plotOptions: {
    series: {pointWidth: 10, pointPadding: 0, groupPadding: 0}
}`

Comment: "What I want is to have some padding between plotlines for a reasonable amount of time series data, say till about 1 hour." -- could you elaborate on that? You want them further apart? Then I'd suggest pre-calculating their positions to simply be further apart, maybe snapping to nearest unused hour or something.

Comment: By "further apart", I mean to be able to add padding between plotlines for them to be legible for cases where plotlines are too close.

Comment: There is no such thing as padding for plot lines. You define value for them and they are drawn. As it was said, you need to calculate the values for the plot lines which include cases where the values are to close. How do you calculate values for the plot lines?

Comment: I don't calculate the values, as mentioned in the question, I get them from the server.

Comment: @AjayKrishna Then you will need to change the plot lines data from the server: before getting them to JS - server side; or after by parsing data in JS before using in Highcharts - client side. It's how **morganfree** wrote - define proper values for the plotLines and they will be placed properly.